# Lost database ibd files. Trying to restore databases from a crash

Tags: mysql, database, mamp

Recently my Hard Drive failed but a repair store managed to recover all of the contents and store it on an external drive for me.

My new clean drive (MacOS Sierra) has mysql 5.7.20 and php installed natively. I am trying to get my databases from my old drive onto my new one. The old drive was using MAMP but now I have mysql/php installed.

The MAMP folder has my databases and some frm files. I tried to copy the folder to my new database folder and while the tables appear it says they don't exists.

```
show tables;
+-----------------------+
| Tables_in_website_x   |
+-----------------------+
| wp_commentmeta        |
| wp_comments           |
| wp_links              |
| wp_options            |
| wp_postmeta           |
| wp_posts              |
| wp_term_relationships |
| wp_term_taxonomy      |
| wp_termmeta           |
| wp_terms              |
| wp_usermeta           |
| wp_users              |
+-----------------------+

select * from wp_options; 
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'website_x.wp_options' doesn't exist
```

The difference I see between the files I copied and the new databases I am creating is that the copied folder is missing matching ibd files to the existing frm ones. Is this the problem?
Is there anyway around this?

Thanks

Comment: `show tables` says the database is named `raeline`. The error message is for a database named `website_x`.

Comment: Sorry I was trying to make it more ambiguous. Edited

Answer (score 0):

I need to know that same thing. i also lost my [website](https://www.birthdayfunnymeme.com/) database and files. How to get back it.